# unable to map stored procedure to my .EDMX file. The selected stored procedure or function return no columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, edmx

I am working on an asp.net mvc 4 web application , and i am using EF version 5, with data base first approach. now i created a stored procedure inside sql server 2008 r2, but when i tried to map the stored procude inside my .edmx file i will get the following error :-

> The selected stored procedure or function return no columns

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your stored procedure does not return any data,  as it what the EF thinks then instead of selecting complex you need to select None.

Comment: can you adivce more on this please ? i mean how i need to modify my code ?